# AJAX button action in foreach

Tags: php, ajax, buttons

I have loop foreach, where i write data and buttons. This code work only from one button, first in loop and the rest does not work.

**JS:**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     jQuery('#przyciskUlubione').click(function() {  

        var data = {
            'action': 'UlubioneDodaj',
            'id_plik': $("#przyciskUlubione").val() 

        };   

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

           if(response == "1"){                                 

                   $("#przyciskUlubione").css('background-color','#4hui7d'); 

                alert("wybor 1");

           } 

            if(response == "2"){

                   $("#przyciskUlubione").css('background-color','#f47121');

                alert("wybor 2");

           }           

        });  

    }); 

    });
```

**PHP:**

```
public function execute(){

         add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_UlubioneDodaj', array( $this, 'UlubioneNiezalogowany' ));
         add_action( 'wp_ajax_UlubioneDodaj', array( $this, 'UlubioneZalogowany' ));

 }

  public function UlubioneNiezalogowany(){

  echo '1';

       wp_die();

  } 

  public function UlubioneZalogowany(){

   echo '2';

        wp_die();

  }   

some_function(){

    foreach(){

         echo '<button id="przyciskUlubione" value="'.$plik['id'].'"> Ulubione </button>';

    }

}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     jQuery('#przyciskUlubione').click(function() {  

        var data = {
            'action': 'UlubioneDodaj',
            'id_plik': $("#przyciskUlubione").val() 
             var $element = $(this);
        };   

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

           if(response == "1"){                                 

                   $element.css("background-color", "#974269")

                alert("wybor 1");

           } 


        });  

    }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have click event firing on ID

```
jQuery('#przyciskUlubione').click(function() {
```

The ID is always unique, there should never be more than one same ID in the HTML.

You can achieve this using class. Assign the same class to all the buttons.

Change your selector to class:

```
jQuery('.przyciskUlubione').click(function() {
```

add value attribute or data attribute to your buttons.

Now, When you will click on any button the click event will be triggered. You now need to fetch value using `this`.

Next step: replace your line

```
$("#przyciskUlubione").val()
```

With this:

```
$(this).val()
```

This should work properly :-)

Comment: Working great, very thanks for help.

Comment: I'm glad I can help :-)

Comment: One thing. Now if i click, all buttton change color instead one.

Comment: Replace line `$("#przyciskUlubione").css('background-color','#4hui7d');` with `this` something llike `$(this).css('background-color','#4hui7d');`. Similarly do it for the line - `$("#przyciskUlubione").css('background-color','#f47121');` to `$(this).css('background-color','#f47121');`

Comment: I did so, but it does not change color at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong ..

Comment: I update question

Comment: If i not change to "this", then work, but all buttons , not one

Comment: I solved problem. I define "var $element = $(this);" before "jQuery.post" and next i write  $element.css("background-color", "#974269");.

Comment: Great! Yes it should be first stored in the variable in order to access it in response.